# Redirection after creating an object, Django

Tags: html, django

I'm new with Django and I'm creating a sport app. 
I allow users to create a match (choosing their team and their style), and I want to redirect them to a specific page (the one of their match) after they create it with a form.

Here is my form:

```
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="radio" name="supporting" value={{teamA.id}}  /> {{teamA}}
    <input type="radio" name="supporting" value="" /> Neutre
    <input type="radio" name="supporting"  value={{teamB.id}}  /> {{teamB}}
    <hr>
    <input type="radio" name="style" value="1" /> Funny
    <input type="radio" name="style" value="3" /> Mixed
    <input type="radio" name="style" value="2" /> Technical
    </br></br>

    <input type="submit" value="Create your match!" />

   </form>

 {% else %}
```

I'm able to redirect a user when he chooses a match that is already created. But I don't know how to redirect to a specific page with the same button that is used to create the match.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view, using `HttpResponseRedirect()` to appropriate url after processing a form you can redirect to new page. Refer doc: [Using a form in a view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#using-a-form-in-a-view)

**Update** : to redirect to match page with id

If your url for match detail page is something like this:

```
url(r'^match_detail/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'myapp.views.match_detail', name='un_mdetail'),
```

Then you can redirect using this

```
HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('un_mdetail', args=(match.id,)))
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, it helped me a lot. But how can I redirect it to a different page for each match that is created, taking the ID of this match?

Comment: You can use the shortcut [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)